# Gravar conteúdo entre <br> no Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
<div class="OSInline" style="width: 100%">
<span data-webbtests="CompraWeb.Request_Edit.AddressWB.expCompanyAdress">
Praça Henrique Lavoie Júnior, 701
<br>
Irajá - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200
</span>
</div>
```

Eu gostaria de gravar o que está entre os 
 e gravar em uma variável

Teria como fazer isso ?

Gostaria que ficasse algo + ou - assim:

> Praça Henrique Lavoie Júnior, 701 Irajá - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200

A `class="OSInline"` está presente em várias partes da tela então acho que não da pra aproveita-la para esse caso

Comment: o código é:                                                                                          <div class="OSInline" style="width: 100%">
<span data-webbtests="CompraWeb.Request_Edit.AddressWB.expCompanyAdress">
Praça Henrique Lavoie Júnior, 701
<br>
Irajá - Rio de Janeiro - RJ - 21231-200
</span>
</div>

Comment: não entendi o imtuito de gravar algo na página com o selemiun. Você pode me explicar ? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

achei na internet a possivel solução

javascript{storedVars.labelValue = storedVars.labelValue.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")}

Eu guardo o meu texto em uma variavel e depois uso esse comando em javascript...porem quando eu utilizo...fica na cor amarela meu selenium IDE e não acontece nada

alguem pode me ajudar ??

Eu gostaria de tira a quebra de linha

Exemplo:

Hello
World

E colocar assim:  Hello World

Alguem pode me ajudar por favor ?